# Spring Boot Gateway app throwing UnknownHostExceptions accessing a registered host

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-cloud

I am attempting to use Spring Cloud Gateway to access a working website.

My application.yml file is below:

```
server:
   port: 8010

spring:
  cloud:
    gateway:
      routes:
       - id: f3ww
         uri: http://testsite:8080
         predicates:
          Path=/factor3/**
    discovery:
      enabled: true
```

This is a simple test gateway, so I am only seeking to access the uri thrugh the path I have defined.

It should be noted that the domain "testsite" is registered on my DNS server. It is in my Intranet, and I can access it without problems.

I am, however, seeing a problem with the Gateway. While I can access the target site by doing:

http://testsite:8080

Attempts to access it using the Gateway:

http://localhost:8010/factor3

causes Spring Boot to generate the following exception:

```
java.net.UnknownHostException: failed to resolve 'testsite' after 4 queries 
    at io.netty.resolver.dns.DnsResolveContext.finishResolve(DnsResolveContext.java:1046) ~[netty-resolver-dns-4.1.67.Final.jar:4.1.67.Final]
    Suppressed: reactor.core.publisher.FluxOnAssembly$OnAssemblyException: 
Error has been observed at the following site(s):
|_ checkpoint ⇢ org.springframework.cloud.gateway.filter.WeightCalculatorWebFilter [DefaultWebFilterChain]
|_ checkpoint ⇢ HTTP GET "/testsite" [ExceptionHandlingWebHandler]
Stack trace:
        at io.netty.resolver.dns.DnsResolveContext.finishResolve(DnsResolveContext.java:1046) ~[netty-resolver-dns-4.1.67.Final.jar:4.1.67.Final]
        at io.netty.resolver.dns.DnsResolveContext.tryToFinishResolve(DnsResolveContext.java:999) ~[netty-resolver-dns-4.1.67.Final.jar:4.1.67.Final]
        at io.netty.resolver.dns.DnsResolveContext.query(DnsResolveContext.java:417) ~[netty-resolver-dns-4.1.67.Final.jar:4.1.67.Final]
        at io.netty.resolver.dns.DnsResolveContext.onResponse(DnsResolveContext.java:628) ~[netty-resolver-dns-4.1.67.Final.jar:4.1.67.Final]
        at io.netty.resolver.dns.DnsResolveContext.access$400(DnsResolveContext.java:65) ~[netty-resolver-dns-4.1.67.Final.jar:4.1.67.Final]
            at io.netty.resolver.dns.DnsResolveContext$2.operationComplete(DnsResolveContext.java:461) ~[netty-resolver-dns-4.1.67.Final.jar:4.1.67.Final]
        at io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultPromise.notifyListener0(DefaultPromise.java:578) ~[netty-common-4.1.67.Final.jar:4.1.67.Final]
        at io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultPromise.notifyListeners0(DefaultPromise.java:571) ~[netty-common-4.1.67.Final.jar:4.1.67.Final]
        at io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultPromise.notifyListenersNow(DefaultPromise.java:550) ~[netty-common-4.1.67.Final.jar:4.1.67.Final]
        at io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultPromise.notifyListeners(DefaultPromise.java:491) ~[netty-common-4.1.67.Final.jar:4.1.67.Final]
        at io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultPromise.setValue0(DefaultPromise.java:616) ~[netty-common-4.1.67.Final.jar:4.1.67.Final]
        at io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultPromise.setSuccess0(DefaultPromise.java:605) ~[netty-common-4.1.67.Final.jar:4.1.67.Final]
        at io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultPromise.trySuccess(DefaultPromise.java:104) ~[netty-common-4.1.67.Final.jar:4.1.67.Final]
        at io.netty.resolver.dns.DnsQueryContext.trySuccess(DnsQueryContext.java:201) ~[netty-resolver-dns-4.1.67.Final.jar:4.1.67.Final]
        at io.netty.resolver.dns.DnsQueryContext.finish(DnsQueryContext.java:193) ~[netty-resolver-dns-4.1.67.Final.jar:4.1.67.Final]
        at io.netty.resolver.dns.DnsNameResolver$DnsResponseHandler.channelRead(DnsNameResolver.java:1301) ~[netty-resolver-dns-4.1.67.Final.jar:4.1.67.Final]
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:379) ~[netty-transport-4.1.67.Final.jar:4.1.67.Final]
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:365) ~[netty-transport-4.1.67.Final.jar:4.1.67.Final]
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:357) ~[netty-transport-4.1.67.Final.jar:4.1.67.Final]
        at io.netty.handler.codec.MessageToMessageDecoder.channelRead(MessageToMessageDecoder.java:103) ~[netty-codec-4.1.67.Final.jar:4.1.67.Final]
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:379) ~[netty-transport-4.1.67.Final.jar:4.1.67.Final]
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:365) ~[netty-transport-4.1.67.Final.jar:4.1.67.Final]
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:357) ~[netty-transport-4.1.67.Final.jar:4.1.67.Final]
        at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline$HeadContext.channelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:1410) ~[netty-transport-4.1.67.Final.jar:4.1.67.Final]
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:379) ~[netty-transport-4.1.67.Final.jar:4.1.67.Final]
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:365) ~[netty-transport-4.1.67.Final.jar:4.1.67.Final]
        at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.fireChannelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:919) ~[netty-transport-4.1.67.Final.jar:4.1.67.Final]
        at io.netty.channel.nio.AbstractNioMessageChannel$NioMessageUnsafe.read(AbstractNioMessageChannel.java:97) ~[netty-transport-4.1.67.Final.jar:4.1.67.Final]
        at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKey(NioEventLoop.java:719) ~[netty-transport-4.1.67.Final.jar:4.1.67.Final]
        at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeysOptimized(NioEventLoop.java:655) ~[netty-transport-4.1.67.Final.jar:4.1.67.Final]
        at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeys(NioEventLoop.java:581) ~[netty-transport-4.1.67.Final.jar:4.1.67.Final]
        at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:493) ~[netty-transport-4.1.67.Final.jar:4.1.67.Final]
        at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$4.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:986) ~[netty-common-4.1.67.Final.jar:4.1.67.Final]
        at io.netty.util.internal.ThreadExecutorMap$2.run(ThreadExecutorMap.java:74) ~[netty-common-4.1.67.Final.jar:4.1.67.Final]
        at io.netty.util.concurrent.FastThreadLocalRunnable.run(FastThreadLocalRunnable.java:30) ~[netty-common-4.1.67.Final.jar:4.1.67.Final]
        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834) ~[na:na]
```

It is my understanding that enabling discovery should cause the application to do a DNS lookup. This does not appear to be happening. Is this a bug in the Spring Cloud Gateway, or am I missing something?

Comment: You need to use `lb://` rather than http and don't need discovery enabled=true

Comment: Changing to lb didn't fix anything -- except that now I am getting 404 errors.

Comment: does it work if you change it to a valid website e.g. www.google.com?

Comment: going from an exception to 404 didn't change anything? Sounds like it did. What discovery system are you using? Is 'testsite' registered as an application?

Comment: As stated in my initial question: testsite is registered on my DNS server. My DNS server is running on my Security Appliance/router.  It can be accessed from anywhere in my Inranet. And yes, I must admit that the move from exception to 404 is an improvement...

Comment: Shawrup: That was a good question! The answer, however, is "No".  Apparently, setting the uri to http://www.google.com causes an exception. Setting it to lb://www.google.com causes a 404 error.